# How do I check if the Multi-select component in Vue js is empty?

Tags: vue.js, components, multi-select

I am trying to check if the Multi-select component is empty. But upon checking it kept telling me it's not null. Do I need to use a v-model for this?

Here's the code for the Multi-select component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Multiselect
      v-model="value"
      mode="tags"
      :close-on-select="false"
      :searchable="false"
      :create-option="true"
      :options="multi_options"
      class="multiselect-orange multiselect"
    />
  </div>
</template>
  
  <script>
import Multiselect from "@vueform/multiselect";

export default {
  components: {
    Multiselect,
  },
  props: {
    multi_options: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },

    inputSelected:{
      required:true,
    },
    method: { type: Function },
    // default: {
    //   type: String,
    //   required: false,
    //   default: null,
    // },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      value: this.inputSelected,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$emit("set-input", this.value);
  },
  watch: {
    value: function () {
      this.$emit("set-input", this.value);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Here's the code where I used the component:

```
<div class="inputHolder">
    <label class="body"> Skills:</label>
    <MultiSelect :multi_options="this.skills" @set-input="setSkillSet" :inputSelected="staffSkills"/>
  </div>
```

Here's the code when I tried to check if the Multi-select is empty:

```
 checkForm(){

        this.errors = []

        if (this.staffSkills) {
          return true;
        }
        if(this.staffSkills === []){
          this.errors.push('Select at least one.');
        }
        if(this.errors.length){ 
          return this.errors
        }
     
        }
      },
```

Comment: "I am trying to check if the Multi-select component is empty" can you include where and how you're trying to do this?

Comment: @yoduh thanks for pointing out I have missed this out

Comment: instead of `if(this.staffSkills === [])`, which will always be false, you should do `if(this.staffSkills.length === 0)`

Comment: @yoduh then what should I do if I want to reset user selection as I tried doing this.staffSkills = 0 (the multiselect values will disappear)

Comment: setting it to 0 will clear the values because now it's just a number which can't hold multiselect values like an array can.  should just reset it to an empty array: `this.staffSkills = []`